# Question has only one answer that is incorrect and upvoted

Tags: discussion, answers, unanswered-questions, wrong-answers

My question from last year [Right aligning text in PdfPCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607970/right-aligning-text-in-pdfpcell) has only one answer (the other answer is really a comment) but that answer is incorrect, yet has a score of 3 and received a bounty.

Is there any way to deal with this? My question remains without a correct answer but because of this incorrect answer it no longer appears in the "Unanswered" list.

I have downvoted and left a comment, but it has gained more upvotes since, and the author has not returned to fix/remove it.

Comment: I can see two answers right now.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the other answer is really a comment.

Comment: It clearly suggests you a solution.

Comment: Do you have a solution yourself? If so, post it.

Comment: I don't - or else I would post it.

Comment: Then you have done all you can for this question. If you think the answer is actively harmful, you can vote to close and delete it, in particular if you think it is of no use to anyone.

Comment: Ins't the answer you qualify as a comment at good tip though? You need to consider the possibility that what you're trying to do simply isn't possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you need an answer, start a new bounty, and explain the issues with the current answers in your bounty message.

Do not just ask the same question again; update the question instead with your research efforts.